A Question about the Doctrine of Eternal Generation
Christians believe Jesus is God's son (God forbid) ontologically, yet they can't answer begetting is a biological process and continue to use filial terms literally? The question is why such huge contradictions in their foundational belief? Accordingly, their criticism on quranic refutation which is not directly addressing them "How can he have a son without consort (female)" is false. Can they address this?

"yet they can't answer begetting is a biological process and continue to use filial terms literally" Christians don't think the Father's begetting of the Son is biological, which pretty much proves they use these terms analogically rather than literally.

@curiousdannii Jesus is God son literally "homoousias" but no the filial terms are analogy? Contradiction again.

Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange. Asking questions is tricky and you might benefit from taking our Tour to understand what we look for in well researched questions: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Welcome to the site, if you want to debate I highly recommend seeking out a better place to do so.  This is not the purpose of this site. If you could rephrase your question to something actually specific instead of multiple half thoughts, we would be able to answer you.  I can't really see what your question is... is it "God doesn't have a wife, how does he have a Son?" o.o

The eternal generation of the Son is a Trinitarian doctrine, which is defined as a necessary and eternal act of God the Father, in which he generates (or begets) God the Son through communicating the whole divine essence to the Son. Generation is not defined as an act of the will, but is by necessity of nature.

This question is fully answered in the previous question Is-the-theory-of-eternal-generation-now-redundant ?.

This question is similar to: Is the theory of Eternal Generation now redundant?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. - John 1:1

Trinitarian Christians believe that the Bible is, literally, the inspired Word of Almighty God and for us it is matter of humility in the face of what God has said to us..  The Word, here, is Logos (in the original Greek) and the term includes not only the communication but also the thought and intent behind the communication and also the rational mind which produces the thought and intention.
It is this word and thought producing rational mind of God which was with God and was God in the beginning.  Because He has perfect, infinite integrity there can be no ontological difference between who God is and what God thinks and says.  The Logos of God is God.
Because the rational processes do not exist apart from the person but are, instead, a product of person-hood the Logos is a generation of God.  Since God is eternal and cannot be imagined as never possessing a rational mind, the Logos is eternally generated.
This generation of Logos is referred to as begetting of a Son by a Father and it is an eternal begetting in that it is without time and without beginning or end.  The apparent biological connection is merely a misunderstanding of analogical language.  God, through Logos, created Biology; He does not need to obey His creation, just as He created Time and remains outside of it.
The Bible talks, for instance, of the arm of the Lord accomplishing things.  Since we know that God does not have a biological arm we understand Divine will and power to be in view rather than an actual arm.  It is a condescension to using terms we understand just as the incarnation of the Son of God was a condescension so that we could be shown who the Father is.
Begotten is an apt term because the creation account indicates that like produces like.  The creation procreates after it's kind:  Cows beget cows and not fishes.  When God begets it is God that is begotten.  He needs not a wife.

This generation of Logos is referred to as begetting of a Son by a Father and it is an eternal begetting in that it is without time and without beginning or end. Up-voted +1.

Isaiah 9:6 mention unequivocal term of child and Christians hold this prophecy refers to Jesus. Strange.

@AbdulMoiz Yes.  The Word/Logos/Son became flesh/Jesus.

Your question makes an assumption that is backwards, because you (as I) are human and see from a human perspective. The begetting of a son by a human mother and father would seem to us to be the literal action and any such relation or action within the godhead would seem to be the spiritual, symbolic reality to which it points. However, it is man that was created in God's image, not the other way around. Thus God's eternal begetting or generation of his Son is the literal reality and humans having children is the symbolic "image" of the divine relationship.
Since you mention the Quran, there is a fascinating prophecy in the Book of Job that relates to this question. Long before the Quran was written, people already had difficulty believing that God could have a son and that a human could be holy enough to please God and be the savior of the world. In Job, his three friends are rebuked by God for speaking incorrectly about Him, whereas Job spoke correctly. The last speech by the friends was uttered by Bildad and is found in Job 25 (ESV version):

1 Then Bildad the Shuhite answered and said:
2 “Dominion and fear are with God;
he makes peace in his high heaven.
3 Is there any number to his armies?
Upon whom does his light not arise?
4 How then can man be in the right before God?
How can he who is born of woman be pure?
5 Behold, even the moon is not bright,
and the stars are not pure in his eyes;
6 how much less man, who is a maggot,
and the son of man, who is a worm!”

Job is presented as negative philosophy. Since the friends were rebuked, we can take the opposite of what they say as truth. Thus we see that there is a man who possesses a dominion in heaven, is called the "light of the world", is right before God, would be born of a woman and who would be known by the title "Son of Man". That man was and is Jesus. However, this prophecy not only prophecies the birth of Jesus, it also symbolically identifies the group that would one day adopt Bildad's error and most forcefully promote it. By referencing the moon and stars, the prophecy is pointing to the Islamic civilization. Many Islamic countries and organizations fly banners and flags that incorporate the moon and stars in their emblems. And they continue, like Bildad, to insist that God has no Son.
This is a summary of arguments presented in my book Plague, Precept, Prophet, Peace and excerpted here:
https://paulchernoch.github.io/paulchernoch/job-course-of-empires.html
https://paulchernoch.github.io/paulchernoch/the-meaning-of-the-beasts-of-job.html
For the flip side, what Job spoke about the characteristics of the ideal and necessary savior, see this:
https://paulchernoch.github.io/paulchernoch/job-description-for-a-savior.html

It is true that human begetting of a child is a biological process, but the Bible is careful to note that the point of "begetting" happens at the time of a successful birth when the new-born infant starts to breathe and the umbilical cord is cut. This is significant when it comes to the non-physical, non-biological biblical phrase about God having one "only-begotten Son", who (Trinitarians claim) is eternally begotten, with no starting point in time.
Please note that the apostles Matthew and Luke employ the Greek word gennetos, to speak specifically of the coming into the world of a new individual by means of a woman. With the virgin Mary, her conception was of the Holy Spirit; it had already happened, after which the angel said she would (future tense) bring forth a Son who would be called Jesus. Matthew 1:20-21 However, this One to be born was not coming into the world as a new creature. This is the point at which Islamic doctrine cannot grasp what biblical "eternal generation" means. But the word gennetos is never applied to the relationship between God as Father, and the One called "his only-begotten Son".
The word in John 1:14 & 18 is monogenes. It signifies something unique [mono = only, one]. And the 'genes' part shows the perceived relationship of that One in the eyes of the heavenly Father. If the Greek word was left half-translated as just "only", causing a bad translation of "God's only Son", that would mean a solitary Son, with no other sons of God, but the Bible does speak of many sons of God. However, none of them were physically 'begotten' by God. When we read of "God's only-begotten Son", this deals with the unique relationship between God as Father and this Son who, we are told in John chapter 1 was the eternal Word, who was with God in the beginning, and who was God, then becoming born of the virgin Mary.
This answer shows how and why the term 'begetting' cannot be used literally when speaking of that which is Spirit and which is eternal. The literal, and the physical, can only apply literally to that which is physical. God is not physical.
"God is Spirit", Jesus told a woman at a Samaritan well (John 4:24), his precise words in Greek being "Pneuma 'o Theos". A reasonable question follows: 'How can this Eternal Spirit have a Son?'
By eternal generation, in one spirit, is how.
Otherwise, spiritually darkened minds will imagine three gods with no divine relationship conjoining them; or one god who remains utterly and incurably alone.
The Bible refutes that last sentence, and upholds that pen-ultimate sentence.

I edited a typo. Please check my correction in case the mistake is mine own.
